# IF / ELSE statements in sql

Tags: sql, if-statement, select, statements

My SQL statement:

```
select * 
from categories 
where onair = 1 and City LIKE 's%';
```

First part:

```
select * 
from categories 
where onair = 1
```

second part:

```
and city like 's%';
```

If city column is not `null`, then I want to execute second part too. Otherwise, execute only first part.

Answer (score 3):

You can create this behavior by a combination of the logical `and` and `or` operators:

```
SELECT *
FROM   categories
WHERE  onair = 1 AND (city IS NULL OR city LIKE 's%');
```

Answer (score 1):

The case statement is your friend...

```
select *, 
case when City like 's%' then City
else '' end as City 
from categories where onair=1
```

That will only return City if it is like 's%'.  Otherwise, it will return blank.  Your other criteria is safely separate..